# Run a Servlet with Tomcat

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8

I do a very simple `Servlet`:

```
package it;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Set the response message's MIME type.
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
      out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");  // HTML 5
      out.println("<html><head>");
      out.println("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
      String title = "Hello World";
      out.println("<title>" + title + "</title></head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      out.println("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");  // Prints "Hello, world!"
      out.println("</body></html>");
    } finally {
     out.close();  // Always close the output writer
    }
  }
}
```

Build this class in `Eclipse IDE`. So, I put the generated file .class in `Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/MyServlet/WEB-INF/classes/it` because my java file is in a package called it.

Then, in `WEB-INF` folder, i create the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.4">
<display-name>My Web server Application</display-name>

<servlet>
 <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>it.MyServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I run `Tomcat Service` in Windows (I know that it is running because I see the tomcat welcome page at http://localhost:8080).

So, when I type the address `http://localhost:8080/MyServlet/hello` but I get always a 404 status error, The requested resource is not available.

I read many tutorials about this topic but I can't understand where the problem is. Could anyone help me?

Comment: better to build a war and deploy it in tomcat, using its console for starters.

Comment: @SajanChandran I'd even say that building a war is the only sane way

Comment: Why http://localhost:8080/MyServlet/hello ? You put the class in the root webapp (at http://localhost:8080) and you map the servlet to /hello, so the url is http://localhost:8080/hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path

```
Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/MyServlet/WEB-INF/classes/it
```

is the wrong place.

The directory immediately beneath `webapps` indicates the application name, e.g. something at `Tomcat/webapps/foo` would be accessed at URL `http://localhost:8080/foo`. `ROOT` is special, it indicates the root application: `http://localhost:8080`.

The WEB-INF directory should be just underneath the application directory. If you want your application to be at `http://localhost:8080/myServlet`, put WEB-INF at

`Tomcat/webapps/MyServlet/WEB-INF`,

and your class at

`Tomcat/webapps/MyServlet/WEB-INF/classes/it`

Comment: Now it works. It's very strange because every tutorial I read reported to put my project in ROOT folder. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You can do that if you want, then you'd put WEB-INF at `Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF` and access your project at `http://localhost:8080/`. Tomcat comes with a ROOT application already which you'd need to remove first, but I'd suggest sticking with `myServlet` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your application at this path:

```
Tomcat/webapps/MyServlet/WEB-INF/classes/it
```

instead of in `ROOT` directory